# Reset chrome local storage data every day

Tags: api, google-chrome, local-storage

I would like to reset the data that I have stored in the user's local storage to be 0 every day. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Store an expire date in the local storage. 
if current date is greater than the expiration clear the LS.

if you have any code that isn't working we will work with you on fixing that too.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny suggestion,
Instead of clearing everything everyday you can just over write if that is possible.